# Кастомный валидатор срабатывает дважды

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, валидация

Если класс помечен как `@Validated`, то cущность, у которой по крайней мере одно поле помечено моей кастомной аннотацией `@Unique`, будет проверена дважды. Более того, в первый раз валидатор будет иметь заинжекченный контекст и сервис, а во второй раз все будет null. Мне кажется, что из-за `@Validated` сущность проверяется дважды, но я не понимаю, почему и даже почему без внедренного контекста и сервиса?

Если класс не помечен, сущность проверяется нормально, даже с моей пользовательской аннотацией. Но валидация параметров не работает, например, `publicString someFunction (@RequestParam ("email") @Email String email)`, и если отправить явно не email адрес, то всё пройдёт в сервис, а вот с `@Validated` на классе уже выдаст сообщение, что email не подходит.

Класс, который обслуживает аннотацию

```
public class UniqueValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Unique, Object> {

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Autowired
private FieldValueExists service;
private String fieldName;

@Override
public void initialize(Unique unique) {

    Class<? extends FieldValueExists> clazz = unique.service();
    this.fieldName = unique.fieldName();
    String serviceQualifier = unique.serviceQualifier();

    if (!serviceQualifier.equals("")) {
        this.service = this.applicationContext.getBean(serviceQualifier, clazz);
    } else {
        this.service = this.applicationContext.getBean(clazz);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(Object o, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
    return !this.service.fieldValueExists(o, this.fieldName);
}
}
```

Аннотация

```
@Target(FIELD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueValidator.class)
public @interface Unique {
    String message() default "Field is not unique";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    Class<? extends FieldValueExists> service() default FieldValueExists.class;
    String serviceQualifier() default "";
    String fieldName();
}
```

Часть кода из сущности, поля которой проверяются моим валидатором

```
@JsonRootName("userCreate")
public class UserModelCreateDto {

@Size(min = 4, max = 32)
@NotBlank
@Unique(fieldName = "login", serviceQualifier = "userServiceImpl")
private String login;
```

Контроллер

```
 @RestController
 @Validated
 public class AuthenticationController {

     private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(AuthenticationController.class);

     @Autowired
     private UserService userService;

     @Autowired
     private ModelMapper modelMapper;


     @PostMapping("/sign-up")
     @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
     public UserModelDto saveUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserModelCreateDto userModelCreateDto, BindingResult result) {
         if (result.hasErrors()) {
             throw new ValidationException(getValidationErrorsAsString(result));
         } else {
             UserModelDto user = userService.save(userModelCreateDto);
             LOG.info("User #" + user.getId() + " has been create account");
             return user;
         }
     }
```

Bean

```
@Bean
public Validator validator (final AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory) {

    ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byProvider( HibernateValidator.class )
            .configure().constraintValidatorFactory(new SpringConstraintValidatorFactory(autowireCapableBeanFactory))
            .buildValidatorFactory();
    return validatorFactory.usingContext().getValidator();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо отключить валидацию, которую производит `Hibernate`.

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none
```